# Issue loading tensorflow 2.9.1 model in tensorflow 1.5.0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have trained a U-net model in tensorflow using version 2.9.1, but the data I would like to run it on is stored a server which doesn't have AVX so is not compatible with recent tensorflow versions. I have installed tensorflow version 1.5.0 on the server, but I am having trouble loading the model.

To save the model I am trying:

```
#tf version 2.9.1
@tf.function
def serving_default(input):
  return {'output': model(input)}
signature_function = serving_default.get_concrete_function(tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 352, 352, 1], dtype=tf.float32))

model.save('tf_model_3', signatures={'serving_default': signature_function})
```

And to to load the model I am trying:

```
sess = tf.Session()
meta_graph = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,["serve"], 'tf_model_3')
```

And this is the error that I am getting:

```
File "/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1838, in import_meta_graph
    **kwargs)
  File "env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 660, in import_scoped_meta_graph
    producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
  File "/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 316, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 433, in import_graph_def
    _RemoveDefaultAttrs(op_dict, producer_op_list, graph_def)
  File "env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 211, in _RemoveDefaultAttrs
    op_def = op_dict[node.op]
KeyError: 'StatefulPartitionedCall'
```

Any guidance that can be offered on where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.